# how to check the values of each variables from a resultant matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have sum of 3 cell arrays

```
A=72x1
B=72x720
C=72x90
resultant=A+B+C
size of resultant=72x64800
```

now when I find the minimum value with row and column indices I can locate the row element easily but how can I locate the column element in variables?
for example 
after dong calculations for A,B,C I added them all and got a resultant in from of <72x(720x90)> or can say a matrix of integers of size <72x64800> then I found the minimum value of resultant with row and column index using the code below.

```
[minimumValue,ind]=min(resultant(:));
  [row,col]=find(result== minimumValue);
```

then **row got 14 and column got 6840 value**..
now I can trace row 14 of all A,B,C variables easily but how can I know that the resultant column 6480 belongs to which combination of A,B,C?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `find`, use the [`ind` output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html?s_tid=doc_srchtitle#bupsfln) from the `min` function. This is the [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) for `minimumValue`. To do that you can use [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(resultant),ind);
```

It is not quite clear what do you mean by `resultant = A+B+C` since you clearly don't sum them if you get a bigger array (72x64800), on the other hand, this is not a simple concatenation (`[A B C]`) since this would result in a 72x811 array.

However, assuming this *is* a concatenation you can do the following:

```
% get the 2nd dimension size of all matrices:
cols = cellfun(@(x) size(x,2),{A,B,C}) 
% create a vector with reapiting matrices names for all their columns:
mats = repelem(['A' 'B' 'C'],cols);
% get the relevant matrix for the c column:
mats(c)
```

so `mats(c)` will be the matrix with the minimum value.

---

**EDIT:**

From your comment I understand that your code looks something like this:

```
% arbitrary data:
A = rand(72,1);
B = rand(72,720);
C = rand(72,90);
% initializing:
K = size(B,2);
N = size(C,2);
counter = 1;
resultant = zeros(72,K*N);
% summing:
for k = 1:K
    for n = 1:N
        resultant(:,counter) = A + B(:,k) + C(:,n);
        counter = counter+1;
    end
end
% finding the minimum value:
[minimumValue,ind] = min(resultant(:))
```

and from the start of the answer you know that you can do this:

```
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(resultant),ind)
```

to get the row and column of `minimumValue` in `resultant`. So, in the same way you can do:

```
[Ccol,Bcol] = ind2sub([N,K],c)
```

where `Bcol` and `Ccol` is the column in `B` and `C`, respectively, so that:

```
minimumValue == A(r) + B(r,Bcol) + C(r,Ccol)
```

To see how it's working imagine that the loop above fills a matrix *M* with the value of `counter`, and M has a size of `N`-by-`K`. Because we fill *M* with a linear index, it will be filled in a column-major way, so the row will correspond to the `n` iterator, and the column will correspond to the `k` iterator. Now `c` corresponds to the `counter` where we got the minimum value, and the row and column of `counter` in *M* tells us the columns in `B` and `C`, so we can use `ind2sub` again to get the subscripts of the position of `counter`. Off course, we don't really need to create *M*, because the values within it are just the linear indices themselves.

Comment: presumably 64800 has something to do with 720*90*1 = 64800 ... but I agree, it's still nowhere near clear what the question is

Comment: resultant is actually in this form:                                                                    `resultant=A+B(:,i)+C(:,j); where i=720 and j=90`